# Inherit message handling behaviour

Tags: scala, actor, traits

I have some events in my model and some handling logic. I want organize communication logic throw Actors. But how I can inherit handling logic without specifying `act()` in each concrete class

Simplified example

```
class Event {}

case class FooEvent(str : String) extends Event
case class BarEvent(i : java.lang.Integer) extends Event

trait FooListener extends Actor {
  def act() {
    react{
      case FooEvent => print("foo received")
    }
  }
}
trait BarListener extends Actor {
  def act() {
    react{
      case BarEvent => print("bar received")
    }
  }
}
class ListensOnlyBar extends BarListener{}

//can't be done: 
//error: overriding method act in trait FooListener of type ()Unit;
//method act in trait BarListener of type ()Unit needs `override' modifier
//class ListensBarAndFoo extends FooListener with BarListener{
class ListensBarAndFoo extends FooListener with BarListener{}
```

Comment: @Kipton Barros, This is what question about. Is there any way to combine them?

Comment: @Kipton Barros, `FooEvent`s should be handled by `FooListener` and `BarEvent`s by `BarListener`.

Comment: I see, then tenshi has a nice answer. What you want isn't really something that can be done with inheritance. By the way, if you put "override" modifiers on your `act()` methods, then linearization will make the left-most `act()` method (from `FooListener`) win in the subclass (`ListensBarAndFoo`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react` expects `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` and you can nicely compose them together. Here is an example:

```
type Listener = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]

val foo: Listener = {
  case FooEvent => print("foo received")
}

val bar: Listener = {
  case BarEvent => print("bar received")
}

case class GenericListener(listener: Listener) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    react(listener)
  }
}

GenericListener(bar)
GenericListener(foo orElse bar)
```